# Help Solving and Understanding a Temperature Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, sturm-liouville

Consider the following temperature problem:
$$u_t(x,t)=ku_{xx}(x,t), \;0\leq x \leq \pi,\;\; t,k >0$$
with boundary conditions:
$$u_x(0,t)=u(0,t)$$
$$u_x(\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
I know the function $u$ will be in the form fn an infinite series $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n y_n(x)T_n(t)$$

But I am quite confused on what the functions $y_n$ and $T_n$ are. I also wish to know how I can compute the coefficients $c_n$ in terms of the function $f$.

I know that I should, to solve this, consider the following Sturm-Liouville problem:

$\text{Given parameters }c > 0 \text{ and } \beta > 0, \text{ let } y=y(x) \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq c. \text{ We have }$
$$y''+ \lambda y=0$$
$\text{ with boundary conditions }$
$$y'(0)=\beta y(0),$$
$$y'(c)=\beta y(c),$$

I am aware that if $c=\pi, \beta=1$, this SL problem describes the temperature problem above. How is this so? I would love an explanation on how temperature problems are associated with SL problems in general.

As for the functions $y_n$ my best guess is that they are the eigenfunctions associated with the SL problem. If this is the case, since $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue for the SL problem, is the $n=0$ term for $u(x,t)$ simply 0?

Explanation into any of these would be helpful, I don't quite understand how to solve this temperature problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that can be solved using separation of variables, which is accomplished by looking for separated solutions $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$:
$$
    u_t = ku_{xx} \\
    X(x)T'(t)=kX''(x)T(t) \\
    \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=k \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}
$$
Because the left side depends only on $t$ and the right side depends only on $x$, there must be a separation constant $\lambda$ such that
$$
          \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-\lambda,\; -\lambda=k \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}.
$$
This leads to solutions $T,X$, in terms of $\lambda,k$ and new constants $A,B,C$:
$$
         T'(t)=-\lambda T(t),\;\; X''(x)+\frac{\lambda}{k}X(x)=0 \\
    T(t)=Ae^{-\lambda t},\\ X(x)=B\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}x\right)+C\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}x\right)
$$
The boundary conditions $X'(0)=X(0)$ and $X'(\pi)=X(\pi)$ become
$$
   B\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}=C,\\ \;\;B\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}\pi\right)-C\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda} {k}}\pi\right) \\
  = B\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}\pi\right)+C\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}\pi\right)
$$
The $\cos$ terms in the second equation cancel because of the first equation. Therefore, the eigenvalue equation is the following equation in $\lambda$:
$$
    B\left(\frac{\lambda}{k}+1\right)\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{k}}\pi\right)=0,
$$
which has solutions $\lambda=-k$ and $\lambda=kn^2$ for $n=0,1,2,\cdots$.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to be telling me. Is $T(t)$ in your solution the $T_n(t)$ in the problem? If so, what happened to the indexes of n? The same is true of $X(x)$. Is $X(x)$ supposed to be $y_n(x)?$ What about the indexes? I also still don't understand how to find the coefficients I mentioned $c_n$ in terms of the function f(x). I want the final answer in the form of an infinite series, as stated in the original problem. With your solution, we don't have an infinite series. How can I get this infinite series solution? Also how is this particular SL problem linked to

Comment: this heat problem? What is it about the boundary conditions specifically that relate it to this temperature problem?

Comment: @RungSoup : I assume you've worked through a few problems like this before. Just as a reminder ... The eigenvalues are determined by the spatial ODE using the homogeneous endpoint conditions. They are shown at the end of my post. Then, using those $\lambda_n$, you can solve for the $T_n$ terms. The resulting solution is $u(t,x)=\sum_{n}C_nX_n(x)T_n(t)$, and the constants $C_n$ are determined by the initial condition $u(0,x)=f(x)$ through the Fourier orthogonality conditions.